# sidekiq for production (heroku, rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer, sidekiq

I have a rails app on heroku and redis is installed. I'm sending out the contactmailers with sidekiq. Development environment works perfectly, according to the stats (localhost:3000/sidekiq) the mailers are delivered. In production the mails get enqueued (visible in stats), but never get sent out.
I checked my sidekick logfile which says: "'production' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test"]".

When it comes to configuration the sidekiq site says: "The Sidekiq configuration file is a YAML file that Sidekiq server uses to configure itself, by default located at config/sidekiq.yml. **It is only necessary to create** the file if you need to set advanced options, such as concurrency pool size, named queues, PID file location, etc."

I didn't deviate from the basics (using default queue), so according to this I should not create the config file at all. Despite of this I saw bunch of different solutions, but I have no clue how to make this work.

########EDITED from here

I made 3 changes and something went wrong:

created config/init/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])
```

created procfile

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v
```

and in the commandline:

```
$ REDIS_PROVIDER: REDISTOGO_URL
```

at the moment I get this in heroku logs:

```
2015-09-23T17:45:06+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.165 sample#load-avg-5m=0.16 sample#load-avg-15m=0.13 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=13274380kB sample#memory-cached=495244kB sample#memory-redis=295456bytes
2015-09-23T17:46:24+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.115 sample#load-avg-5m=0.15 sample#load-avg-15m=0.125 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=13274528kB sample#memory-cached=495244kB sample#memory-redis=295456bytes
2015-09-23T17:47:00.650410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2015-09-23T17:47:00.651110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2015-09-23T17:47:46.264012+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2015-09-23T17:47:46.264012+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2015-09-23T17:47:37+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.075 sample#load-avg-5m=0.13 sample#load-avg-15m=0.12 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=13271788kB sample#memory-cached=495380kB sample#memory-redis=295456bytes
...
...
...
2015-09-23T18:14:24+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.095 sample#load-avg-5m=0.125 sample#load-avg-15m=0.12 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=13272136kB sample#memory-cached=495440kB sample#memory-redis=295456bytes
2015-09-23T18:15:29.144536+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v37 created by szilard.magyar@gmail.com
2015-09-23T18:15:29.144419+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b0303dd by szilard.magyar@gmail.com
2015-09-23T18:15:29.212308+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-23T18:15:29.212337+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-09-23T18:15:20+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.095 sample#load-avg-5m=0.125 sample#load-avg-15m=0.12 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=13272136kB sample#memory-cached=495440kB sample#memory-redis=295456bytes
2015-09-23T18:15:56.813737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2015-09-23T18:15:56.814701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2015-09-23T18:16:02.295335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -p`
2015-09-23T18:16:04.220054+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2015-09-23T18:16:04.220024+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2015-09-23T18:16:05.048801+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-09-23T18:16:05.087911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-23T18:16:05.088846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-23T18:16:12.443341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -p`
2015-09-23T18:16:15.603477+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2015-09-23T18:16:15.603501+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2015-09-23T18:16:16.582868+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-09-23T18:16:16.594516+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-23T18:16:17.306558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=appfaskyn.herokuapp.com request_id=a621bcd8-13b8-4bbe-a10b-d15dcda0f464 fwd="46.139.53.208" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-09-23T18:16:17.309666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=appfaskyn.herokuapp.com request_id=0b639f31-3c32-4d12-b871-245995c960cd fwd="46.139.53.208" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What should I do?

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment

Comment: I changed some things and everything is screwed up at the moment. BroiSatse, do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you actually using RedisToGo - or actually using Heroku Redis? The instructions on the Sidekiq page are for RedisToGo.

Comment: heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev -a appfaskyn

Comment: Commands I used in development: $bundle exec sidekiq, then for production:  $heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev -a appfaskyn;;; $bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -e production (this one probably didn't work out). At least app was working. Since then I've added the 3 changes I listed in my question afterwards, and the app is not working at the moment in production, but development works fine and sidekiq sends out the mailers